# Drupal7 Radio button value to datasabe is not working

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

Adding textbox ,radiobuttons and submit button is working fine..

```
enter code here:
```

'                    $form = array();

```
              $form['name'] = array(
             '#title' => 'Your Name',
              '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#size' => '30',
                    );  

                 $active = array(0 => t('Blog-Url'), 1 => t('Twitter-Name'));

             $form['settings']['active'] = array(
                '#type' => 'radios',
                 '#title' => t('Enter nature of the name'),
                '#default_value' => isset($node->active) ? $node->active : 1,
                '#options' => $active,
                  '#description' => t('Enter nature of the name, and characteritics.'),
                    );

                    $form['submit'] = array(
                     '#type' => 'submit',
                   '#value' => 'Submit',        
                       );

                      return $form;'
```

// When Submit button is clicked the action take place and insert into database not working..

`                     function sform_add_form_submit($form,$form_state){

```
                 $name = trim($form_state['values']['name']);   
                     $formwem= $form_state['values']['settings']['active'];
                $query = "INSERT INTO twittername (`name`,'Blogurt','Twitter_name')                                                    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')";
                    $result = db_query($query, $name, $formwem ); `
```

Please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

Try re-writing your query to:

```
$name = trim($form_state['values']['name']);   
$formwem = $form_state['values']['settings']['active'];

$result = db_query("INSERT INTO twittername (name, Blogurt, Twitter_name)                                             VALUES (':name',':blogurt',':twitter_name')", array(':name' => $name, ':blogurt' => $formwem, ':twitter_name' => $formwem));
```

Though I'm not sure which form field populates the two columns `Blogurt` and `Twitter_name`. Can you please explain?

Comment: In this case form has two radio buttons blogurl and twitter_name if user select blogurl then database has name of person,blogurl/(1) and Twitter_name/0  or if  user select twitter_name then database stores  the name of that person . blogurl(0) and twitter_name(1)....

Comment: Its depends on end-user they can either select blogurl or twitter_name  not both if user select blogurt the database stores 1 under blogurt and 0 at twitter_name  and if user select twitter_name then vise-versa..